# What is a term or phrase that captures different kinds of indicators?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

If you are monitoring and recording trends in unrelated things, then how do you clearly say this without really mentioning the specific things you are looking at?

For example, a statistician or an economist might be monitoring trends (time series / year over year changes in numbers, changes in policies, rates, etc.) in:

- gdp, inflation, interest rates
- gang related deaths, crime rates, arrests
- suicide rates, death by drug overdose, etc.

The above examples range from pure economic indicators to more social/well-being type indicators. Is there a term or phrase that would capture all of these things?

> Monitored and recorded trends in [xxx]

The best I could come up with is this:

> Monitored and recorded trends in areas of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.  But I don't think you need to

You are "Monitoring and observing trends"  You don't want to mention the specific things that you are observing, so don't mention them.

If you still want a word, you could use "indices", "indicators", or "statistics".

It does seem odd not to mention anything about what you are observing.  So perhaps "monitoring and observing trends in various indices relating to social deprivation" or similar.